# How to connect to database file to extract the data?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I need some help with my PHP code. I want to connect to the database file called myChannel.db to extract the data from the rows, but I have got no idea how to do that by using this code:

Here is the config:

```
<?php
  define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
  define('DB_USER', 'myusername');
  define('DB_PASSWORD', 'mypassword');
  define('DB_DATABASE', 'mydbname');
  $errmsg_arr = array();
  $errflag = false;
  $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

  if(!$link) 
  {
    die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
  }
  $db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);

  if(!$db) 
  {
    die("Unable to select database");
  }
?>
```

Here is the get-listing.php script:

```
<?php
$errmsg_arr = array();
$errflag = true;
$link;

//Connect to the database
require_once('config.php');

$qrytable1="SELECT id, channels, programme_title, programme_description, programme_start_date, programme_end_date FROM tvguide WHERE channels='$channels' && id='$id'";
$result1 = mysql_query($qrytable1) or die('Error:<br />' . $qry . '<br />' . mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) 
{
  //output the data for channels, programme_title, programme_description, programme_start_date, programme_end
}
?>
```

The code will only allow me to connect to mysql and nothing is else.

Can you please show me an example how I could connect to myChannel.db and extract the data from the columns called channels, programme_title, programme_description, programme_start_date, programme_end where the channels is matched?

Comment: Of course it only lets you connect to MySQL. What else would you expect it to let you connect to with functions starting with `mysql_`? SQL Server? Oracle? What DBMS does `myChannel.db` belong to? We can't tell you how to connect to it if you can't tell us what the DBMS is that made it. If `myChannel.db` is a MySQL database, then you just need to make the proper adjustments to the code you have to use your database name and write a SELECT to get your data, both of which you can do yourself easily.

Comment: You need to write a data query and send it to your mySQL database

Comment: @KenWhite I am expect to connect to sqlite3 database

Comment: I for one have no idea what it is you're asking. You also mention a file called `myChannel.db` but I see no clear reference for it.

Comment: Not with a MySQL library, you're not. Google *sqlite3 PHP*. (And learn to actually **read** code you're trying to copy/paste. The fact all of the database access code uses `mysql_` as a prefix should tell you it's for working **only** with MySQL.)

Comment: *"The code will only allow me to connect to mysql and nothing is else."* - All I see is an empty `while` loop. Your question is unclear.

Comment: *"I am expect to connect to sqlite3 database"* - That should have been in your question as soon as it was posted.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I know I should have but never mind. When I try this `$db_connect = new SQLite3('myChannel_1.db') or die("Could not open database");` the error did not display when the filename is incorrect?

Comment: if the filename is incorrect, then you need to set error reporting on to catch and display and check for the real connection/query errors

Comment: @Fred-ii- how I can do that?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php --- https://www.daniweb.com/programming/web-development/code/442441/using-php-sqlite3-with-error-checking --- http://php.net/manual/en/class.sqlite3.php

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You asked for an example... this was my solution for querying geocoordinates from mySQL database.  I call all of this in my php file...

```
     //set up a MySQL query, this is the data you are asking for.  This asks for all data from tabele 'shelters'.   Be sure to call your specific table.  
$sql = "SELECT * FROM shelters;";

if(!$results = $link->query($sql)){
  die("Query Unsuccessful");
}

//Here I create a value map and pull out the results I care about from my request query.  
$valueMap = array();
while ($data = $results->fetch_assoc()){
    $valueMap[] = array(
      'title' => $data['title'],
      'lat' => $data['lat'],
      'lng' => $data['lng'],

    );
}
//encoding it into JSON is more manageble for me, but you will have to parse it into a javascript object in your index file. 
  $JSONData = json_encode($valueMap);

 //heere you want to echo your data in order to retrieve it in your index file. Has the functionality of connecting to an API
  echo $JSONData;
```

Hit me up in the comments with any more specific questions.

Comment: thank you very much for this but how I can connect to sqlite3 database?

Comment: When I try this $db_connect = new SQLite3('myChannel_1.db') or die("Could not open database"); the error did not display when the filename is incorrect? any idea?